# Failure Entity Framework Core 3.2 update while entity has association with Identity User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, tracker-enabled-dbcontext

Here is a new issue. Trying to update entry in the Database. Note, this entry has dependency on User. I conducted the same  logic I used to do when  I didn't have user association with the item without any issue. However, now it is giving me grief. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is the details on the exception note:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The property 'Id' on entity type 'Medication' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)
   at MedicalManager.Models.Repositories.MedicationRepository.UpdateMedication(Medication medication, String UserId) in C:\bite-us\stackoverflow\mmm_development\MedicalManager\Models\Repositories\MedicationRepository.cs:line 71
   at MedicalManager.Controllers.HomeController.Edit(Medication medication) in C:\bite-us\stackoverflow\mmm_development\MedicalManager\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 123
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Comment: The code is available in public repository:  https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development  of branch: Update_Failure . https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development.git BTW, I want to really thank again the  team members here helping me through this. Made some good progress with the helps. This update is being a roadblock to the excitement, any  help will be greatly appreciated. Feel free to pull the source code and push with new commits & comments. Looking forward to hearing from you guys. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Bite-us,In your medication, it should include `Medication.Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Because your relationship is one to many,if your medication don't include Id,It will not know which data to update.It will cause this issue.

You should check the source of the `medication`,and add the `Id` you need to update into the `medication`.

You can see my test here.
[image]

Comment: It worked. Bingoo!!!!!.. I kind of had to play  a trick to pass the item id into the form by having a hidden field for the item id value. However, is there any other way, to pass this information to the controller. Because medication id could be PII or secured data therefore, would like to avoid it being hacked in client side or browser.

Comment: Hi @Bite-us,Since your relationship is one-to-many, you cannot determine the target data you want to update, so you can only get the target data by displaying the specified Id.